# How to measure Firefox extension's resource use?

Tags: firefox-extensions, resources, resource-monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Firefox plugin for analyzing the performance and crashes of Firefox Plugins?](https://superuser.com/questions/433166/a-firefox-plugin-for-analyzing-the-performance-and-crashes-of-firefox-plugins)

I have a "short list" of extensions that I'm considering for global installation, but first I want to remove from this list any serious resource hog.

Is there a way to measure how much of various key resources (specially memory, cpu, and startup time) is used by a specific Firefox extension?

Thanks!

Comment: `about:memory` maybe?

Comment: This won't tell you everything you want to know, but try running it with and without the extension enabled and check its total memory usage using Windows' Task Manager (or equivalent for your OS) in each configuration. Depending on the extension, you may have to do specific things in each session to cause it to be utilized.